# Table value not updating

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I have a total value that gets updated, however it will only show the updates on a page refresh.  How could I go about only updating this single table value?  It uses a Java Play Framework with Scala templating.  I am assuming I would have to use AJAX to try and refresh just that class name?  I currently use AJAX to send the id of the item I would like to disable when calculating the totals.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Table HTML / SCALA**

```
<tr class="dofont" style="font-weight:bold">
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    @for(total <- order.getTotals()) {
        <div class='total'><td>@total</td></div>
    }
</tr>
```

**Javascript / AJAX**

```
<script>
    $('.make-switch').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        jsRoutes.controllers.Builder.setDisabled(id).ajax({
             success : function(data) {}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your ajax call working properly? If yes, then write response from server side, get from success method's data and set that value in the div.

Comment: My ajax works, and sends the correct id to be set to disabled.  However  wouldn't the newly changed data be located in the class total?

Comment: What method of server-side is invoked from your ajax call? In that method write response that you want to set in div.